# How to setup different confirmation email per webform instance

Tags: 8, webforms

Background:
I have a ContactUs webform made by Drupal 8 webforms contrib module and used that ContactUs Form on 3 different pages.

Is it possible to setup 3 different confirmation emails per instance?

Many tanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a custom confirmation message from a Webform node to the Webform email handler using a token like `[webform_submission:node:field_confirmation_message]`

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jrockowitz for you answer. I need to send confirmation emails. I don't get if above solve this situation

Comment: The same concept can be applied to the email handler.